# How can I read all stored Cookies in browser

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

all I would be like to read all cookies stored in a browser. Using standard Javascript API I am not able to read it. But is there a way I can read all cookies not just the cookies register via my website.

Comment: No, that would be a hell of a security problem.

Comment: assuming by "all" you mean from other websites? You realize why that would be a bad thing, right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/775416/is-it-possible-for-one-browser-to-read-write-cookies-of-another-one

Comment: I think you should delete this question before you receive more downvotes and drop below 50 rep again ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser security will deliberately prevent this. If you could do this, it would be possible for you to steal data from other websites.

This question has already been asked and  answered on our sister site [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/775416/is-it-possible-for-one-browser-to-read-write-cookies-of-another-one)