# How to get all stored cookies in ones browser with a Python 3 script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies

Is there a way to get all stored cookies for a certain browser?

I searched the web but only [referrals to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45721504/how-can-i-read-all-stored-cookies-in-browser) or something like this
[Retrieving all Cookies in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812420/how-to-get-cookies-from-web-browser-with-python) which works fine after some adjustments but only give me the cookies from a specific site.

But I want to read out all cookies let's say which are stored by Chrome or Safari.

How can I do this with python?  Is there a global system variable I can request or read?

Comment: Example for Firefox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49502254/how-to-import-firefox-cookies-to-python-requests

Comment: Thanks for the link. This was exactly what helped. I didn't image that it get stored in sqlite. Same seems true foe chrome.

Answer (score 6):

I think you need this module https://github.com/borisbabic/browser_cookie3. With that you can simply get list of all cookies for Chrome by:

`import browser_cookie3
cookies = list(browser_cookie3.chrome())`

Now just parse the list as you need to.

Comment: Thanks. This gives me a great template to use. But it seems to be written for windows?

Comment: You are welcome :) About the Windows - I tested it on my Ubuntu 18.04 and it works. I guess there is some polyfill for all systems in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an option for Safari?
using

```
cookies = browser_cookie3.chrome()
```

Returns:

> browser_cookie3.BrowserCookieError: Can not find Safari cookie file

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35468235)